# How can I write data to and update HTML5 cached web pages while working offline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, caching

In the application I am writing, a user captures information about a person via an online form. When they have completed the form they save their work, repeating this process several times in a session. When they hit 'Save and End Session' they are returned a list of the several person instances they have just saved, all data being saved to a server.

I wish to replicate this functionality in an offline app. Using HTML5 I understand how to cache pages, and how store the JSON form data in localStorage using raw Javascript (or perhaps Angular.js cache).

But is it possible to dynamically update cached webpages with cached data while offline? how, for example,  can I write the the cached form data to a cached copy of the list page, updating that page with the data just produced, all during the offline session?

I cannot find an answer to this one. All suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, you want to dynamically update the html view while offline.
If you are using Angular, this is pretty simple.
You just have to cache also the JS controller, not only the html file (set it in the `cache.manifest`). The page will have the same functionality as the online app then.
 But if you want to send the stored offline data back to the server when offline, you can write a simple code that will:

1. Save the parameter in localStorage, which will mark if the data was saved while running online/offline app (you can recognize onine/offline by sending AJAX request to an existing part of the app, which is not available offline (so not cached one))
2. When app runs then in online mode, it will collect all the data stored offline and send it to the server

Comment: Thanks very much, doodeec; this is very helpful. It gave me a solution and enabled me to understand other issues as well.